# checkbox whit React js and state

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, axios, state

I am creating a filtering form to filter my data based on the checkboxes which will have a value of true or false but I don't know why I have the value `undefined`.

#### My code:

The Constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      rfp:false,
      rfx:false,
      rfp_x:false,
      allclassification: false,
    }
this.onChange =  this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
   }
```

`onChange`:

```
onChange(e){
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
}
```

`onSubmit`:

```
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const FilterClassification = {
        // classification
        rfx:this.state.rfx,
        rfp:this.state.rfp,
        rfp_x:this.state.rfp_x,
        allclassification:this.state.allclassification,
    }
    console.log(FilterClassification)

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser",FilterClassification )
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
<fieldset>
<legend>RFX/RFP:</legend>
<div className="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange={this.onChange}  value={this.state.rfx} name="rfx" id="rfx" />
  <label className="form-check-label"  name="rfx">RFX</label>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

  <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange={this.onChange}  value={this.state.rfp}  name="rfp" id="rfp"  />
  
  <label className="form-check-label" >RFP</label>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

  <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange={this.onChange}  value={this.state.rfp_x}  name="rfp_x" id="rfp_x"/>
  <label className="form-check-label" >RFP(X)</label>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


  <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input"  onChange={this.onChange} name="allclassification" id="allclassification" />
  <label className="form-check-label"  name="all" id="all">ALL</label>
</div>
</from>
```

The screen of result in console:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

What should I do to change `undefined` to false value?

Answer (score 0):

Provide checked prop to checkbox instead of value

```
 <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange={this.onChange}  
 checked={this.state.rfp_x}  name="rfp_x" id="rfp_x"/>
```

And rather than binding functions in constructor use => arrow functions

- like this:- onSubmit=e=>{ //your code here }
- do same  for onChange and remove this.onChange =  this.onChange.bind(this);
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this); in constructor

Comment: i have already the same error please can you explain ?

Comment: just change value prop with checked in checkbox input